# how can I set #attributes for each item of selectlist

Tags: forms

I know I can set style for form items with `#attributes`  but I want set background for select list (drop down) items, how can set `#attributes` for each item of select list(dropdown) in form_alter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function MYTHEME_select($vars) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'size'));
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-select'));

  return '<select' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . MYTHEME_form_select_options($element) . '</select>';
}


function MYTHEME_form_select_options($element) {
  // Build up your own version of form_select_options here
  // that takes into account your extra attribute needs.
  // This will probably involve inspecting your custom FAPI property,
  // which we'll call #extra_option_attributes
}
```

And your code in the form would be something like:

```
$form['select'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => array(1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two'),
  '#extra_option_attributes' => array(
    1 => array('title' => 'Test title'), // Attributes for option with key "1",
    2 => array('title' => 'Test title'), // Attributes for option with key "2",
  ) 
);
```

In MYTHEME_form_select_options() you can then inspect the element's #extra_option_attributes key (if one exists) to see if you need to physically add any more attributes in the HTML you create.

Credit to @Clive for this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261224/adding-attribute-to-option-element-using-forms-api-drupal-7/9264589#9264589 .. Cross posting here in Drupal Q & A